# How do I remove characters from an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

I want to strip a Unicode character (\u0097) from NSString....

Answer (score 3):

This is simplest to remove \u0097:

```
NSString * deGremlinedString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0097" withString:@""];
```

The docs for that method [are right here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6).

Alternatively, if the starting string is an NSMutableString, then [you can use this method](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-BCIFDIAF):

```
[theMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0097" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [theMutableString length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSCharacterSet* badUnicodeCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\u0097"];
theString = [[theString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:badUnicodeCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use two backslashes to escape the backslash. So `@"\\u0097"`. I'm not positive, but I read [this page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UniCode) that says:

> the reason for that is the first backslash is an escape in the string literal (so you can do things like @"\""); the second backslash is the one that makes it into the string to be parsed by NSConstantString. --boredzo

Sorry if this is wrong, but it was what I understood from the page.